# Enumerate Com-Object Collections via IEnumerable

Tags: c#, collections, com, outlook

I want to iterate an Outlook.Selection (which is a collection that implements IEnumerable) or an Outlook.Items Collection (which also indirectly implements IEnumerable) through a method. So the method parameter could be one of those.

I can´t figure out, how to implement the parameter for the method correctly.
I´m so far at this point:

```
Outlook.Selection items1 = activeExplorer.Selection;
Outlook.Items items2 = currentFolder.Items;

// How can i input these as parameter into the method below?

// The Method to iterate looks like this so far:
        private void MethodX<T>(IEnumerable<T> items)
        {
            foreach (var item in items)
            {
                //...
            }
        }
```

I don´t know if this is possible anyway because of using COM-Objects...
Maybe there´s another way?!

Comment: If they implement `IEnumerable` then you can use `.Cast<T>`

Comment: This doesn´t work: MethodX(selection.Cast<Outlook.Selection>());

Comment: This seems to work: MethodX(selection.Cast<object>()); But don´t know if this is a good solution?!

Comment: You have to cast to the collection element type, not the collection type.  Which can be one of [many possible interfaces](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff866278.aspx), depending on what is selected, so you probably prefer OfType<>() instead.

Comment: Just for the record, enumerating *all* items in an Items collection is a bad idea. Either work with a subset of the Items collection (Find/FindNext/Restrict) or use a "for" loop and explicitly release each item at the  end of each iteration.

Comment: @DmitryStreblechenko Yes, i iterate through the Outlook.MailItems via for loop and indexed access and release all at the end of the method.

Comment: If you are using a "for" loop, then you will not be able to use an enumerator. And you must release all items inside the loop to avoid running out of RPC channels.

Comment: @DmitryStreblechenko Yes, i changed to an IList.. Ok, I´ll release inside

Comment: That will not help. This is a problem with COM enumerators (IEnumVariant) in .Net - they keep all collection items referenced until the loop exits. Do not use enumerators with Outlook objects unless the collection is small (e.g. message recipients).

Comment: @DmitryStreblechenko But then, how should I iterate through the collection? Because you said "or use a "for" loop and explicitly release each item at the end of each iteration." Should I rest with IEnumerable and use for each?

Comment: See the answer below

Answer (score -1):

In reply to a comment above - to use a "for" loop, try the following:

```
Outlook.Items items2 = currentFolder.Items;
for (int i = 1; i <= items2.Count; i++)
{
  object item = items2[i];
  Outlook.MailItem mailItem = (MailItem)item;
  if (mailItem != null) //you can have objects other than MailItem
  {
    //use mailItem here
    Marshal.ReleaseComObject(mailItem );
  }
  Marshal.ReleaseComObject(item);  
}
```